# downloading graphics.h

Tags: graphics, c

I'm trying to download graphics.h, but when I get to the part where I have to extract the libgraph-1.0.2.tar.gz file, I can't find that file anywhere on my directory. I am trying to download graphics.h on ubuntu.

these are the steps I took

1)
First add the Universe repository (since some required packages are not available in main repository):

sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
Second install build-essential and some additional packages:

2)
For versions prior to 18.04:

sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-1.8 
guile-1.8-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev 
libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev 
libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev 
libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev build-essential
For 18.04: From Ubuntu 18.04 guile-2.0 works and libesd0-dev is deprecated. For this you need to add repositories of xenial in sources.list.

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
Add these lines:

3)
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe
4)
Run sudo apt-get update.
Then install packages using:

sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-2.0 
guile-2.0-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev 
libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev 
libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev 
libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev

5. I got stuck on this step, I could not find this tz.gz file.

Now extract the downloaded libgraph-1.0.2.tar.gz file.

Comment: Please describe the steps taken, and their results.

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you running?